# How to autoload files using compose autoload and psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to autoload files and to have an entry point for my app. I'm not using framework, using OOP.
My composer.json file is:

```js
{
    "require": {
        "tebazil/db-seeder": "^0.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "vendor\\": "vendor/",
            "App\\": "src/classes/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/functions.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

In this file functions.php I want to include the vendor/autoload.php file.
I'm not sure how to create this entry point for the app and there to require this vendor/autoload file because I've used frameworks for this goal.

This is the current content of the functions.php but there is another issue as I render the index.html view file, but there is ajax request.
However, what is the correct way to have a bootstrap file for the app and autoload necessary files?

```html
<?php
namespace App;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Db;
use App\User;
class Functions
{

    public function render()
    {
        ob_start();
        include(__DIR__ . '/../index.html');
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $content;
    }
}

if(!($_GET && array_key_exists('name', $_GET))) {
    $functions = new Functions();
    $functions->render();

}

if($_GET && array_key_exists('name', $_GET)){
    $user = new User();
    $users = $user->getUsers();
}
```

Comment: You have a circular dependency there. autoloaded files are included by the autoloader, but your autoloaded file includes the autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see you don't need to register "functions.php" in composer. Your application may have the following structure:

```
- app_folder/
  - src/
    - classes/
    - index.html
  - public/
    - functions.php
  - vendor/
    - ...
```

Where "functions.php" file serves as application entry point. Direct your web server to "public" folder, thus all other files will be accessible to your php code, but not to users.

You may implement your routing or similar tasks in "functions.php" and place components like models and views to "src", and you will get simple yet structured application.

Comment: The only addition i made to your original structure is the concept of "public" folder, which should be the only thing accessible through web server. Put there your entry point and all assets, which will be served by web server - for example, images. Everything else is up to you and your task. You can quite successfully solve tasks in pure php, using specific libraries when needed.